# jQuery Ajax error 200 parse error

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

I have read many articles related to my predicament but I do not understand my what my problem is so please someone help explain it to me:

I want to use jQuery ajax to post a value to a PHP file:

```
$().ready(function(){
"use strict";
$("#ansSubmit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateScore.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{ 
            data : JSON.stringify(flag)
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.reply);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status + "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });  
    $("#infoDiv").load("updateScore.php"); // to see what $_POST contains
  });
});
```

The flag variable being sent is an integer.

Here is my updated updateScore.php (the PHP file I am posting to):

```
<?php
session_start();

$returned = array("reply" => "no data received");

if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
   $returned["reply"] = $_POST["data"];
}

print_r($_POST);

echo json_encode($returned);

?>
```

"no data received" is returned so at least I know it reached updateScore.php but now I need help establishing why it not sending anything through - I am 100% sure flag has a value.

Additional information:

1. mime.types has all JSON options active.
2. console.log(data) returns Uncaught Reference Error: data is not defined.
3. errorThrown returns Parse error: unexpected < in position 0 - I can get this to say unexpected A in position 0 but it is still an empty array that is being sent.
4. print_r($_POST) returns Array()

Comment: Have you checked that flag is defined at the time you call strigify?

Comment: I am using XAMPP with PHP 5.6.14 and jQuery 1.12.0

Comment: Yes, I monitor it with an alert. It returns an integer between 0 and 5.

Comment: Are you accessing your xampp website via `localhost` or by typing the file name in the browser address bar `file:///c:\xampp\htdocs\index.php`? You must use the `localhost` method for ajax to work.

Comment: I use localhost/php/main.php. A html button with the id "ansSubmit" fires the jQuery script (tested and it works) to post to updateScore.php. The updateScore.php script also works if manually insert flag.

Comment: could you post the code on "updateScore.php", how are you reading the session variables (data)

Answer (score 1):

First you tell the server that you are sending it JSON:

> ```
> contentType: "application/json",
> ```

Then you pass an object to `data`. This gets encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which **is not JSON** although it happens to have JSON embedded *inside* it).

> ```
> data:{ 
>     data : JSON.stringify(flag)
> },
> ```

Then in the PHP you try to read from `$_POST`

> ```
> if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
> ```

… but `$_POST` is empty because you told the server you were sending JSON so didn't try to decode it.

---

Remove this line:

> ```
> contentType: "application/json",
> ```

… because it is a lie that breaks your code.

---

*Alternatively*

You could actually send JSON:

```
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify(flag),
```

… and then read it from the raw request body instead of (the still unpopulated) `$_POST`.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: 5 start explanation, bravo! What baffles me is with both your suggested methods I get a parse error: Unexpected token < in JSON position 0 - where would a "<" come from - is it trying to parse html? If so why if dataType is set to json?

Comment: @user3458861 — `dataType: "json"` tells jQuery to parse the response as JSON no matter what the content type response header says (it also sets an Accept request header expressing a preference for JSON). If it gets `<` then that usually indicates that the server is returning HTML (and it errors because the client was expecting JSON). The code you've provided *shouldn't* return HTML though, possibly the server isn't configured to support PHP so it is returning the raw source code of the PHP program (or possibly you load loading everything from a `file://` URI and the server is being bypassed)

Comment: I run other php scripts without issues and I load everything from localhost/somePath. My mime.types have application/json and text/json active. I honestly don't know what else to try but I see you are ranked under the top 0.01% of stack overflow users so I'm hoping you might have another idea or 2?

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, you are expecting a json object to be returned BUT you are echoing `it works ....`.

**try this sample code in php:**

```
$returned = array("reply" => "not found");

if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
     $returned["reply"] = "It works!" . $_POST["data"];
}

echo json_encode($returned);
```

basically this sample code sets an array `returned` with `reply` by default as `not found`. If data is available, it sets `reply` to your message. Then after that it `echoes` a json version of the message.

Comment: My reply is still undefined, if I include contentType: "application/json" and dataType: "json" then I get a 404 file not found error. I wouldn't call it progress but atleast its something new...

Comment: This post was very helpful, it is returning the reply but not appending the "It works!" . $_POST["data"]; so my isset() is failing. I am 100% sure I that flag has a value before being sent but console.log(data) returns: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined, any idea why?